# password validation failing using mechanize/python

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

First, I just want to say that there are a number of similar questions out there, but none are working for me.

I'm a python/scraping newbie, and I'm trying to use the mechanize module to log onto a website. However, when I present the correct credentials in the form it fails to log in. Here's my code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

br.open('https://www.chess.com/login')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['c1'] = 'username'
br.form['loginpassword'] = 'password'

br.submit()

print br.open('http://www.chess.com/home/game_archive?member=username&page=1').read()
```

The final print command shows the source code for the page as though I'm not logged in. If I enter the same credentials through chrome, access the final url, then view the source I can see the correct (logged in) code, so the username and password shouldn't be the problem. Anyone have a good guess about what is going on?